# simple bar plot with mithril.js and d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, bar-chart, mithril.js

I am very very new to javascript and mithril.js. I am trying to create a very simple bar plot using mithril.js and d3.js. But, I am not having any luck even getting the axis in place.

Firstly, I created a `mithril` "svg" component and appended a `mithril` "g" compent as follows:

```
var g = m(gView, {transpose:"translate(10, 10)"})
var svg = m(SVGView, {width: 100, height:100}, g)
```

where `gView` and `SVGView` are as follows:

```
var gView = {
view: function(vnode) {
return m("g", vnode.attrs, [vnode.children]);
    }
}

var SVGView = {
    view: function(vnode) {
    return m("svg", vnode.attrs, [vnode.children]);
    }
}
```

Now I created a simple axis scale and an axis function as follows:

```
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 10])
        .range([0, 40]);

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
```

How do I add my `xAxis` to my mithril component `svg`?

I saw many many examples where they just use `.call(xAxis)` but this works only with a `d3.select()`. I don't want to use and cannot use a `d3.select()` as I have to work with mithril.

If my question/code is stupid or if my approach is totally wrong please excuse me. I searched for a simple bar plot build using mithril and I couldn't find anything. So, any help is appreciated or even a redirection to a source where I can read about plotting graphs in mithril is apprecated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is not a great way to perfectly fit d3 into a mithriljs app without just letting d3 run a subtree of the dom by itself.

I created a simple example based off your code above and this mithril js example from the documentation at: [bootstrap-fullcalendar-example](https://mithril.js.org/integrating-libs.html#bootstrap-fullcalendar-example)

Note that the `BarChart` component **always tells mithril that it is only rendering a `div` inside of its `view`** therefore after its first draw it will never be redrawn again even though d3 is manipulating the dom below that `div`.  This is **critical** because you don't want to draw something with d3 and then have mithril draw over it or the opposite.

In order to manipulate the bar chart you will have to use `d3.select` inside the `App` using the dom element that was saved off in `barChartEl`.  I created a silly example of this that just pushes the bar chart to the right once and then you can reset it with the other button.  I don't know enough about d3 sorry but you get the idea.  Also note that `barChartEl` is the `div` and not the `svg` node but I can still select down to the `g` or you could directly select the `svg` there.

This code was written to use **d3 v5** and **mithril 2.0.4**.

```
// Assumes that d3 available.


function BarChart() {
  return {
    oncreate: function (vnode) {
      var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, 10])
        .range([0, 40]);

      var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
      d3.select(vnode.dom).append("svg")
        .attr("width", 100)
        .attr("height", 100)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(10,10)")
        .call(xAxis);
    },
    view: function (vnode) {
      return m('div');
    }
  }
}

function App() {
  
  var barChartEl = null;
  return {
    view: function (vnode) {
      return m('div', [
        m('button[type=button]', {
          onclick: function () { 
           d3.select(barChartEl).select("g").attr('transform', "translate(50,10)");
          }
        }, 'BarChart Right'),
        m('button[type=button]', {
          onclick: function () { 
           d3.select(barChartEl).select("g").attr('transform', "translate(10,10)");
          }
        }, 'BarChart Reset'),
        m(BarChart, {
        oncreate: function (vnode) { 
          // Save off bar chart element in case we need to reference it
          // with d3.select. 
          barChartEl = vnode.dom; 
        }
      })]);
    }
  }
}

m.mount(document.body, App);
```

Also this example code uses the closure style components as seen in the documentation here in order to store state: [closure-component-state](https://mithril.js.org/components.html#closure-component-state).

Comment: Ah! thank you very very much. This fits my need perfectly. I don't even want to reference the bar plot, just export it as a static mithril component. This idea just works perfectly. Thanks once again for the simple explanation!