# How to incorporate D3 svg elements into mithril.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, mithril.js

I have been working with a framework using mithril.js and wish to add [this script](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/43a860bc0024792f8803bba8ca0d5ecd) that draws an interactive tree into a component on my website.

So far, I just placed the JS code inside the `script` tags into my application, and I know that normally, the DOM object generated is obtained by calling `svg.node()`. But I know I can't return that from my object's `view` method, and instead need to return something of the form `m(...)`. I tried looking at sources like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62924959/simple-bar-plot-with-mithril-js-and-d3-js) but couldn't find a solution to my problem in them. **Is there a known way for incorporating D3 SVG graphics into mihtril.js?**

If you wanted to look at the code I have right now:

```
export default class TreeModal extends Modal {
    content() {

        var treeData = ... // some data

        ... // Other code; irrelevant to this question
        
        var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom).append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        
        // Some other code adding more functionality

        // At this point, svg contains the SVG object which I wish to display
        return svg.node(); // Raises ILLEGAL CONSTRUCTOR error; how to adapt this for Mithril.js?
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for all the help!

**UPDATE:** It seems like what a `Modal` is is crucial to my problem, because the API I use actually asks me to implement the `content()` method in any subclasses of `Modal`. I looked in `Modal.js`, and the relevant bit is:

```
export default class Modal {
    view() {
        return (
        <div>
            ...
            {this.content()}
            ...
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Ideally, the solution would not have to override the `view()` method of `Modal` and only would include changes to `content()` in `TreeModal`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really hard to write correct code without knowing the implementation or documentation of the base Modal class.  To work around the API you have mentioned we can render a div in content with a random id that we use later to find it after it is placed into the DOM tree.  Then inject the SVG into that div and use D3 as you normally would.  I'm not sure if D3 needs cleanup but that would be done in `onremove`, again make sure to call the parents `onremove` if necessary.

I use JSX in `content` but I wasn't able to test its format.

```
export default class TreeModal extends Modal {
    constructor() {
        // @TODO: Not sure what Modal's constructor looks like.
        super();
        // Create a random DOM id we share between content() 
        //and oncreate().
        this.svgContainerId = 'svg_container_' + 
            Math.floor(Math.random()*1000000000) + 1;
    }
    oncreate(vnode) {
        // @TODO: Check if Modal implements this method or not.
        // super.oncreate(vnode);

        var treeData = {} // some data

        ... // Other code; irrelevant to this question
        
        // USE our predefined id to lookup the div rendered in content
        // and inject our SVG into that container.
        var svg = d3.select(document.getElementById(this.svgContainerId)).append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
            .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom).append("g")
            .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        
        // Some other code adding more functionality
    }
    content() {
        // render a plain DIV with our predefined id that never changes.
        // this JSX is untested
        return (<div id="{this.svgContainerId}"/>);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for your explanation - unfortunately, I noticed that with the API I use, it doesn't actually recommend that I change the view() method. I've edited my post to include the details of my situation; would it still be possible to incorporate the D3 script with this object structure?

Comment: I thought because the modal had a view method that it was a mithril component, but it seems to be using JSX.  How are you trying to use the modal in your mithril app?

Comment: I just want it to be shown upon clicking a button. (Let me know if this doesn't answer your question.) I'm also a little hazy on what is a Mithril component is, because from this link (https://mithril.js.org/jsx.html) it seems like JSX and virtual nodes created using `m()` can be used interchangeably?

Comment: @paulinho Sorry I forgot about that, you're right you can use JSX.  This is hard to solve without viewing Modal and how you use TreeModal.  I've updated the answer with something else to try.  The JSX is not tested.

Comment: This works nicely! One question: since `oncreate` is called before `content`, why doesn't the line that looks for the object with `id=this.svgContainerId` fail? Hasn't that element not been created yet?

Comment: View is called to get the specification of what to render and subsequently calls content.  Then mithril decides what to "render" (or alter in later calls after taking diffs).  On the first render the DIVs in view and content are created (because diffs say they are missing) and injected into the DOM by mithril and then oncreate is called. So it is actually the reverse order of what you thought.  That is how hyperscript works, m(), I assume jsx works similarly.

Comment: @paulinho You can read more about how rendering works in mithril.js here https://mithril.js.org/render.html#how-it-works and also the next section here https://mithril.js.org/render.html#why-virtual-dom   .  It becomes more natural after using it, the virtual dom, for a while, especially if using hyperscript.  I love it now versus dealing with html and the DOM.

Comment: @paulinho Last note, in your case here with D3, you are having to work harder to side-step this VDOM diff system in order to let D3 manipulate the DOM directly below that DIV in content.  Once that div with the id is rendered by mithril both `view` and `content` return the same vdom spec so mithril never manipulates the dom below that content div again therefore allowing D3 to manipulate the subtree without interference from mithril and letting both systems coexist independently.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to craft a really elaborate explanation!