# Having issue of rendering Mapbox map from any ID other than "app"

Tags: javascript, html, rendering, mapbox-gl-js, mithril.js

I'm trying to implement Mapbox gl gs into a project I'm building with Mithril and am having issues with getting a map to render from any ID other then "app". Within the body of my html I have a div called app so it makes sense why that works. The problem is, I dont want the map to be rendered both from the initial app location and from the location I want it to be rendered from in my case "map".

**html**

```
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no" />
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- bootstrap -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <!-- google fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caudex:wght@700&family=Rock+Salt&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <!-- mapbox -->
  <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.1.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
  <link href='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.1.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />

  <title>NoN</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="app"></div>
  <script src="/bundle.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

and my current **Map Component**:

```
const m = require("mithril");
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

mapboxgl.accessToken = MAPBOXTOKEN
let  map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'app', // container id
        // container: 'map', // container id

        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // style URL
        center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
        zoom: 9 // starting zoom
    });


const Map = {
    
    view: (vnode) => (

        <div>
        <div id="app"></div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Map
```

I would like to be rendering only from the div with the id "map" like so:

```
const m = require("mithril");

import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiZG10cmVlcyIsImEiOiJja2w4ZHN0NzEyMHI0MzJxbTNuOW56YXlsIn0.jNw5dh1j09irmOYBCTykAg'
let  map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      
       container: 'map', // container id

        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11', // style URL
        center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position [lng, lat]
        zoom: 9 // starting zoom
    });


const Map = {
    
    view: (vnode) => (

        <div>
        <div id="map"></div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Map
```

but when doing so I get this error:

`VM472725 bundle.js:1642 Uncaught Error: Container 'map' not found.`

Answer (score 0):

This question is a problem similar to this question because it involves integrating a 3rd party widget with Mithril: [Question #62924959](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62924959)

You need to place the map initialization code, `let  map = new mapboxgl.Map(...)` inside the `oncreate(vnode)` method of the mithril component.  Then you can either pass the dom element directly with vnode.dom or use the id of whatever you set in the mithril `view` method.  I think what is happening is that the initialization code runs before the dom element is ready and therefore the `Container 'map' not found` error occurs.

Documentation for the `oncreate` method:
[oncreate](https://mithril.js.org/lifecycle-methods.html#oncreate)

Mithril has the following example code when using a 3rd party tool (ie. not aware of mithril's re-rendering, etc.):
[3rd party integration](https://mithril.js.org/integrating-libs.html)

To make your code more re-usable you could use a dynamic id on the dom element and use that in the oncreate method to pass to the map intialization code.